# Ionic storage is not setting value

Tags: ionic3, typescript2.0

I keep getting undefined value when trying to set value with ionic storage.
Though i do see the value in console on the first instance of console.log

See output values in code:

```
GeneratePBKDF2(pbkdf2Password) {

  console.log("New password created: " + pbkdf2Password);
  // Output: New password created:PBKDF2$sha256$901$89G9D/PkC521fqOt$9gNgGt6rkhs5UeVlp2oJfI0l3CLpUgk6

  this.storage.set("TempPass", pbkdf2Password);
   // Error output: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined

   console.log("Test Output" + pbkdf2Password);
   // Output: null
  }


Start() {
  var password = PasswordGenerator.generate({length: 20,numbers: true});
  MosquittoPBKDF.createPasswordAsync(password, this.GeneratePBKDF2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your this is not pointing to component scope as you add your method as argument. Try this approach via fat arrow:

```
GeneratePBKDF2 = (pbkdf2Password) => {

  console.log("New password created: " + pbkdf2Password);
  // Output: New password created:PBKDF2$sha256$901$89G9D/PkC521fqOt$9gNgGt6rkhs5UeVlp2oJfI0l3CLpUgk6

  this.storage.set("TempPass", pbkdf2Password);
   // Error output: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined

   console.log("Test Output" + pbkdf2Password);
   // Output: null
  }
```

Comment: Cool;) yeah just keep in mind that inside the brackets “this” points into different scope